# artifactory webinterface doesnt show properly

Tags: artifactory

I installed artifactory (2.6.5) at a linux server. Started it and now i want to configure some stuff over the webinterface. But the webinterface doesnt look like it should. 
Only thing I edit after the installation was the default port in the jetty.xml file.

No idea what the reason for this look (see Screenshot) is. So any help is appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things could cause this:

1. Residual browser caches (very likely).
2. UI Resources blocked by the browser (quite unlikely).

The first case can be easily solved by clearing the browser's cache and re-loading the page.

The second case might require you to investigate which resources are being blocked (using the browser's console) and tweak the security settings/rules.

Comment: Its not the first case. I cleared the browser cache couple of times and refreshed the page, even tried the page out with other browser, but the same problem. For the second: Tweak the security settings of the browser? Over the console I see just some warnings, but all concered to some css where the whole declarations are skipped because of reasons like "declaration expected, but * found.

Comment: The browser couldnt load the css files, because it had no permissions. I set them for the directory where the files are in, but not for the parent directory.. pretty silly, but your second point led me to it.